# How can I change the size of the Google Voice Typing window?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-input-method

In my input method, I've followed [these instructions from the Android Developers' Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html) to add a button to activate Google Voice Typing. This works perfectly, but there's a stylistic problem.

The "input window" for Google Voice Typing is about twice the height of my input method. One of the big advantages of voice input is that you don't need any GUI at all, and one of the USPs of my input method is its small real-estate need, so it seems silly to take up half the screen only when you switch to voice.

Is there a way I can tell the Google Voice Typing window what height to be, or replace or hide its user interface completely? I know I could use the speech recogniser API directly behind my own GUI, but that workaround has other shortcomings: I need the "record sound" permission in my app, the speech recogniser can't use the input type of the text field, it doesn't automatically use the offline recognition data if available, and it means duplicating all the functionality to show alternatives as spans in the `TextView`.